# Yii2 - mailer - send message to email rows in database

Tags: arrays, string, yii2, send, mailer

**Greetings,**

i need to send email to several recipients that are stored in a table named mail which has a field called email.

In my controller i created an action that Query the table mail for the emails.

Later i tried to use the implode() function separated by comma, but obviously it didn't work because of mailer policies.
It generated the wrong format -> "email1@mail.com, email2@mail.com, email3@mail.com".

Tried also a for each loop and the serialize() function without success.

The json_encode() function is close to what i need, separate an array of emails to something like -> "email1@mail.com", "email2@mail.com", "email3@mail.com".
But it appends the field name before the value and it is not accepted by mailer policies.

**So far i'm stuck with the following code:**

```
public function actionSucesso()
{
    $query = new Query;
    $query->select('email')
    ->from('mail');
    $command = $query->createCommand();
    $enderecos = $command->queryAll();

    $enviar = json_encode($enderecos);

    Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
        ->setFrom('atf@website.com')
        ->setTo($enviar)
        ->setSubject('Oferta de jogo no site da ATF.')
        ->setTextBody('Aceda em: http://atf.besaba.com/index.php?r=playschedule%2Findex2')
        ->send();
    return $this->render('sucesso');
}
```

I think in order for the mailer to work and send the message the correct format needs to be: ->setTo("mail1@mail.com", "mail2@mail.com", "mail3@mail.com")

**Is there a way of solving this problem?
Many thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get array of email with numeric indexes call `queryAll()` method with `$fetchMode` parameter *\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN*, and then just pass returned array to mailer's `setTo()` method. Like this

```
$enderecos = $command->queryAll(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

//$enviar = json_encode($enderecos); <- this line no needed

Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
    ->setFrom('atf@website.com')
    ->setTo($enderecos) //you pass an array of email addresses
    ->setSubject('Oferta de jogo no site da ATF.')
    ->setTextBody('Aceda em: http://atf.besaba.com/index.php?r=playschedule%2Findex2')
    ->send();
```

See [queryAll() documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#queryAll%28%29-detail) and [list of pdo constant](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php) including available fetch modes starting with *PDO::FETCH_*. Also assuming you are using yii2 default mailer, look for [swiftmailer documentation](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#setting-to-recipients) about how to set recipients

Comment: Almost there. The name of the field has gone, but mailer doesn't accept the input and throws error: Address in mailbox given [[["andre73@live.com.pt"],["andregc73@gmail.com"]]] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.

Comment: Tried the other PDO::FETCH_  -> but none has solved the issue. :(

Comment: sorry, misguided you a little, use *\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN* should work

Comment: Unfortunately it did not. It throes error:   Address in mailbox given [["andre73@live.com.pt","andregc73@gmail.com"]] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.

Comment: Perhaps because of the double [[ at the beginning and at the end ?

Comment: You are passing an array, so one [ must be there, but from where does another [ come  from, trying to figure that out

Comment: When i run print_r($enderecos) it returns the correct result like this:     Array ( [0] => andre73@live.com.pt [1] => andregc73@gmail.com )

Comment: well i think its some actual email address issue, try to remove or change address *andre73@live.com.pt* in the list. The second [ also came from the error message, so it is not a problem.

Comment: I have already done that and it did not work, also switched the var by the email 'andre73@live.com.pt', 'andregc73@gmail.com' and it worked fine. So i think it is not email issue but php issue :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80507/discussion-between-tony-and-andre-castro).